# AS3 how to set initial stage size

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flashdevelop, stage

How do I set the initial stage sizing (height/width) if I'm developing in pure AS3 utilizing the FlashDevelop tool?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can right click your project and go to properties to set the dimensions there or you can put the following in your main class declaration:

```
[SWF(width="1280", height="800", backgroundColor="#000000", frameRate="30")]
public class Main extends Sprite 
{
...
}
```